# Get the class methods

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Supposing I have a class like this:

```
class Foo {
  constructor () {}
  foo () {}
  bar () {}
  baz () {}
}
```

How can I dynamically get an array containing `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` (the order doesn't matter)?

I tried using `Object.keys(Foo.prototype)`. That returns an empty array:

```js
"use strict";

class Foo {
  constructor() {}
  foo() {}
  bar() {}
  baz() {}
}

alert(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(Foo.prototype)));
```

However, if we do it in the prototype way, it works fine:

```js
function Foo () {};
Foo.prototype.foo = function () {};
Foo.prototype.bar = function () {};
Foo.prototype.baz = function () {};

alert(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(Foo.prototype)));
```

So, how can I get the same array, but when using the classes?

I guess a solution would be to create a class instance and read the fields from there, but I don't really like it...

Comment: Use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` instead.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you! :) Works.